# TextField Issue: misplacing text when app enters foreground

Tags: ios, uitextfielddelegate

I have an issue with the textField in my app. If the user begins to type in a number then leaves the app and the app returns to foreground the number no longer shows. However, if another number is pressed, the original numbers appear again plus the most recent number pressed. I tried setting the delegate to nil and the text to nil in viewDidDissappear, but that had no effect on the issue. Am I missing something?

```
@interface SignIn : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
```

.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

 self.numberField.delegate = self;

}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

if (textField == self.numberField) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
return YES;

}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if (_authFailedLabel.text != nil) {
    _authFailedLabel.text = nil;
  }
}
```

Please disregard the bad cropping on the images.
[image: User types in number, then leaves app. App remains running in the background.]

Step 1: User types in number, then leaves app. App remains running in the background.

[image: User re-enters the app and numbers are no longer visible in the textField]

Step 2: User returns to app. Numbers are no longer visible.

[image]

Step 3: User types in an additional number and the original numbers reappear, however the numbers are no longer centered.

[image]

Step 4: User types another number and all numbers vanish from view, but will reappear on another addition.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning NO instead of YES for textFieldShouldReturn:

Also:

```
if (_authFailedLabel.text != nil) {
    _authFailedLabel.text = nil;
  }
```

Will clear out the text of that label (was that actually the number label?  not sure with the code sample you supplied)

Instead of setting it to nil, you might want to do something more like this:

```
if (![_authFailedLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
   _authFailedLabel.text = @"";
}
```

Also, try setting it to @"foo" (or something) instead, to see if it's clearing when you don't want it to.

Comment: @jeffery Sorry, I should have been more clear. The authFailedLabel is a label below the textField that displays a string based on a network response. I only added those methods b/c they are the only text field delegate methods implemented.

Comment: can you post the whole class file?  I can't see what would be causing the problem otherwise...